# How to convert JSON (or POJO) to Room Entity?

Tags: android, json, entity, android-room

Having simple JSON, [for instance](https://json.org/example.html):

```
{
    "widget": {
        "debug": "on",
        "window": {
            "title": "Sample Konfabulator Widget",
            "name": "main_window",
            "width": 500,
            "height": 500
        },
        "image": { 
            "src": "Images/Sun.png",
            "name": "sun1",
            "hOffset": 250,
            "vOffset": 250,
            "alignment": "center"
        },
        "text": {
            "data": "Click Here",
            "size": 36,
            "style": "bold",
            "name": "text1",
            "hOffset": 250,
            "vOffset": 100,
            "alignment": "center",
            "onMouseUp": "sun1.opacity = (sun1.opacity / 100) * 90;"
        }
    }
}
```

we can convert it to `POJO` using [sites](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) or [plugins](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9960-json-to-kotlin-class-jsontokotlinclass-) in `Android Studio`. But how to convert it to `Room` `Entities`?

Comment: @a_local_nobody, yes, but it is a manual operation. I want a tool that converts JSON to Entites automatically.

Answer (score 1):

You can just annotate your POJO to create Room Entity. Please check the official doc for more information on this link https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/defining-data

Comment: Thanks! Yes, we can.